# Passing a data frame of multiple columns to an expression by means of the paste function

Tags: r

I have the following random correlated series vector. (Package quantmod)

```
x <- filter(rnorm(100), filter=rep(1,3), circular=TRUE)

#I run the autocorrelation and confidence intervals  
a <- acf(x)
b <- a[[1]]
c <- (b[2:length(b)])
posssignificance_level <- qnorm((1+0.95)/2)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(x)))
negsignificance_level <-  -posssignificance_level

#obtaining the frequency of the autocorrelation
poscorr <- which(posssignificance_level<c)
negcorr <- which(negsignificance_level>c)

#lag the initial series by the different autocorrelation frequencies
posautorrelation <- if(length(poscorr) == 0) Lag(as.numeric(x),0) else    
na.omit(posautorrelation <- Lag(as.numeric(x), poscorr)) 
negautorrelation <- if(length(negcorr) == 0) Lag(as.numeric(x),0) else 
na.omit(negautorrelation <- Lag(as.numeric(x), negcorr))

#Then I make equal the starting point for each column obtained by  
shortest <- min((length(posautorrelation))/(length(poscorr)),
(length(negautorrelation))/(length(negcorr)))
posautorrelation <- tail(posautorrelation, shortest)
negautorrelation <- tail(negautorrelation, shortest)
tpos <- na.omit(posautorrelation); rownames(tpos)<-NULL
tneg <- na.omit(negautorrelation); rownames(tneg)<-NULL

#Producing a dataframe with colnames similar to Lag.4...
c <- data.frame(tpos,tneg) 

#Adjusting the length of x to the minimum lag
correction <- length(x)-length(tpos[,1]) 
z <- x[(correction+1):length(x)]
z <- c(z,0)
```

When I paste the data frame c into the expression below I obtain a vector of the numbers in the columns Lag.4 and similar. Doing paste(colnames(c).. yields the manes of the columns and when appying pastevar to the model matrix at the end I get an error telling me that the object Lag.4... could not be found. The tposs and tneg have each multiple columns and maybe in attempting to put this multiple columns in data.frame by means of listing only tpos and tneg may not be the correct way.

```
pastevar <- paste(c("z[2:length(z)] ~ ", paste(c, collapse=" + ")))
X <- model.matrix(as.formula(pastevar))[,-1]
```

What would be the right way of passing the data frame by means of the paste function as for this to take each column of the data.frame?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: It kind of sounds like he wants `?get` not sure though.

Comment: > pastevar 
[1] "z[2:length(z)] ~ " "Lag.4..."

Comment: Now I get > pastevar [1] "z[2:length(z)] ~ " "c(1.30040703152834,... which are the data of each column

Comment: X <- model.matrix(z2[2:length(z2)] ~Lag.4+Lag.5+...  Would be the result, Lag.. being the columns.

Comment: correction    as.formula(pastebar) = z2[2:length(z2)] ~Lag.4+Lag.5+... Would be the result, Lag.. being the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for the following code:

```
# You want 'names(c)' instead of 'c'
# and don't need the 'c' function 

pastevar <- paste("z[2:length(z)] ~ ", paste(names(c), collapse=" + "))
# [1] "z[2:length(z)] ~  Lag.1 + Lag.2 + Lag.15 + Lag.16"


# You need to pass a data frame to the function 'model.matrix'

X <- model.matrix(as.formula(pastevar), c)[,-1]
#          Lag.1       Lag.2      Lag.15      Lag.16
# 1  -0.74870676  0.01337777  0.96744542  0.17647578
# 2  -2.97027457 -0.74870676  1.61315456  0.96744542
# 3  -3.82279738 -2.97027457  0.53727069  1.61315456
# 4  -3.47817458 -3.82279738  1.54034858  0.53727069
# 5  -2.26750524 -3.47817458  2.26544218  1.54034858
# 6  -1.17946841 -2.26750524  2.64224392  2.26544218
# ...
```

By the way: `c` is not a good name for a data frame since it's also the name of a very basic function.

Comment: Many, many thanks, c was causing the probem, now I see it clear